# C# Exception when using setter of a Control

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

This question is about a soft in C# compact framework 3.5, for windows CE 6.0

When I use the following :

```
control.Location = new Point(iLocationX, iLocationY);
```

I've got an Exception (of type Exception, no more details) with the following stacktrace :

> at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
>    
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control._SetBoundsCore(Rectangle rect, BoundsSpecified bsSpecified)
>       
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Location(Point value)

control is not null, it's an instance of TextBox. If I catch the Exception, I've got the same on

```
control.Size = new Size(iWidthControl, control.Height);
```

I've got the same kind of Exception with this code :

```
if (sender is Button)
{
 Button btn = (Button)sender;
  btn.Font = new Font("Calibri Light", btn.Font.Size, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);                   
}
```

Stacktrace :

> at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
>    
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Font()

It seems that the setter or the getter of the class is sending that exception, but how can I obtain a clear Exception, where I can understand what happen (like with a DivideByZeroException, it's easy :D).

I've got two test hardware, two motorola MC2180. One of them work without throwing Exception, the other one throw a lot of thing. They have both Windows 6.0 (but not the same version), should I search in this direction ?

If anyone have any clue (or C# debug tips), thank you.

Comment: The exception has no `Message`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [how to ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, there is no Message, just an exception of type Exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but in my previous job we saw similar issues with a specific version of the Compact Framework.

In the February 2015 monthly update a bug was fixed:

> [150223_KB3039843](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/3039843/fix-font-setting-changes-in-a-.net-compact-framework-3.5-app-on-a-wind) An exception occurs when accessing the font property of .NET application.

With two otherwise equal devices in hand (MC18), one would run without errors while the other would throw an exception accessing WinForms control's properties. The only difference was the compact framework version used to build the OS. After contacting Zebra they built an image with a newer OS and the problem vanished.

The bug was introduced only a few months prior to the fix, but I'm afraid I don't know the exact numbers.

So the OS version *could possibly* be the cause here.